# Aerospike migrations issue

Tags: aerospike, aerospike-ce

We have a 10 node cluster with version 3.9 running with cold-start-empty false, in which we did the following activity :

- Added a node 10.0.29.212 with version community build 3.13.0.10
  Waited for migrations to finish (new cluster size 11). There were incoming Migrations on only 10.0.29.212 node as expected.
- Added 2 nodes 10.0.29.190 , 10.0.29.135 simultaneously with version community build 3.13.0.10.
  Waited for migrations to finish (new cluster size 13).Incoming Migrations on only these two nodes node as expected.
- Added a node 10.0.29.214 after few hours with version community build 3.13.0.10.
  Immediately after the node was added , the total master objects in the cluster dropped and incoming migrations started on all nodes and we started getting timeouts on cluster.

[image: Please find the image showing migrations attached]

Comment: Cross posted here: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/aerospike-migrations-issue-data-loss/6437.